# Add space after slashes that are not part of html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to add a space after each slash (/) character that is not part of an html tag. So if the content of an element looks like:

```
<strong>Occupational/technical/eduction/training program:</strong><br />
Started before 1/1/12.<br />
More text <i>description</i> more/text/with/slashes.
```

I'd like to add a space after each slash, but not slashes in closing tags (like the </strong>) or in break <br /> tags, as adding spaces after slashes in tags cause browsers to incorrectly render them.

Right now, I have:

```
jQuery("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
    var tdContent = jQuery(this).html();
    slashSpace = tdContent.replace(/\//g, "/ ");
    $(this).empty().append(slashSpace);

});
```

Close, but this adds space to all slashes, including html tags. I set up this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ejp4r/. As you can see, adding space to closing tags renders the second cell incorrectly.

Seems like it should be fairly easy, but I'm drawing a blank. Any ideas?

Comment: don't try to parse html with regex..you could break your code easily..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to using regular expressions, you could traverse the text-nodes to apply what needs to be changed:

```
var textNodes = function textNodes(parent, cb) {
  [].slice.call(parent.childNodes).forEach(function (node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case 1: textNodes(node, cb); break;
      case 3: cb(node); break;
    }
  });
};

$('table').each(function () {
  textNodes(this, function (node) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/\//g, '\/ ');
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ohezud/2/

Comment: As Anirudh suggested, using reg-ex seems problematic, as I'm still experiencing some slight problems with the reg-ex Meagar provided. This works, so I'll use a slightly modified version of what you've provided. Thanks Yoshi!

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression needs to explicitly match only slashes that aren't surrounded by `<` or `>`:

```
tdContent.replace(/([^<])\/([^>])/g, "$1/ $2");
```

In a regular expression, `[^...]` means "match characters *not* in this set". The regular expression will now match `*/*`, but not `</` or `/>`.

[Works](http://jsfiddle.net/Ejp4r/3/).

Comment: I think this is almost it. But is something missing? 

This does ignore the slashes in html tags, but it looks like something funky is happening when the appropriate slashes are replaced - it's also deleting the character right before and after each slash.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, sorry. See David's edit. It was replacing the character matched by `[^<]` and `[^>]` in addition to the slash.

Comment: David's edit seems to correct the character matching problem. Adding this almost does the trick, but it looks like there may be 1 additional issue: 
The date in the first row doesn't have the space added after the second slash. The space is added everywhere else, though. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.text(...)` instead of `.html(...)` like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ejp4r/1/)

Comment: I had tried using .text(), but I need to keep the html tags that may be included.

Comment: Ah, I see @JMurky - then meagar probably got your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get mess with regex, try this:

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {

    var children = $(this).find();

    if( children.length > 0 ) {
        children.each(function(){
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/\//g, "/ ") ); 
        });
    } else {
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/\//g, "/ ") );
    }

});
```